# How to make gatsbyjs sites in Amazon S3 bucket using Amazon Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gatsby

I want to make AWS lambda function that will create new gatsbyjs sites in Amazon S3 bucket. I am familiar with aws lambda but So I need a help that anybody know the steps for that please let me.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just create the site in Lambda and then upload the files to the S3 bucket.

The bucket needs to have all the uploaded files set as *public*, so the following bucket policy needs to be attached to the bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AddPerm",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-gatsby-files/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

A Gatsby site is a Single-Page Application, so all the requests need to be directed through `index.html`. To enable this, select *Static Website Hosting* in the bucket *Properties*. Select *Enable website hosting* and set `index.html` to both *Index Document* and *Error Document*.